# Samba hide disallowed files

Tags: samba

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.2 and samba 4.7.6

i have the following directories:

```
sambashare/
├── dir1
├── dir2
├── dir3
└── dir4
```

and 2 users: **user1** and **user2**

i want to give permission to **user1** to all folders and **user2** only to *dir3* and *dir4*,
is there any option to hide *dir1* and *dir2* directories from **user2**?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I had to use these two params:

```
hide unreadable = yes
hide unwriteable files = yes
```